# Access business logic layer directly from a "small" composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I moved my navigation logic to view models to decouple it from *Navigation Component*, like [here](https://joebirch.co/android/modular-navigation-with-jetpack-compose/).

As it is typical for `Composable` to have [screen-level view model](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodels-source-of-truth), it would mean, that child `Composable`s of that screen-level `Composable` should pass some events to the parent, screen-level `Composable` (via callbacks) that will pass the event in the end to the view model.

This however would require passing the events all the way round through all `Composable`s between composable that caused event to the parent, screen-level `Composable`.

I would say it's fine **in most** of the cases.

However, one example which is not fine, is **a small (not-screen level) UI element** which has **business logic tied to it**. And that business logic is a [cross cutting concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) for the app.

Imagine writing Facebook-like app in Compose. In a variety of different screens you can see users' thumbnails (friends list, members of a group, authors of posts etc.)

And every time you click on a thumbnail, a pice of business logic is executed, which ends up in navigatig you to thumbnail owner's profile.
It's clearly a cross cutting concern and implementing it in a view model for each screen and passing the events up to the screen-level `Composable` seem to cause unncecessary overhead.

**How to handle such "small" (not-screen level) `Composable`s that require access to business logic?**

Using view model for such a small composable may be an option, but feels a little bit strange, as the view models seem to be a default choice for *screen-level* composables.

It may be also possible to achieve it with `CompositionLocal`s, but it seems to be [excatly the discouraged case.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal#deciding)

Comment: Not sure why their navigation actions are in a MutableStateFlow, it should be `Channel(UNLIMITED)` and collected not as state from a `LaunchedEffect(Unit) {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to the ["Thinking in Compose"](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model) article, I think no composable should interact with business logic directly. Each and every composable should only render states that are provided to them. Events should be propagated and handled in the `ViewModel` of the screen (or high-level screen composable).

In your case of *Facebook-like app*, clicking on thumbnail is an event which should be propagated back to the `ViewModel` of the screen. Then, based on the screen and logic you are trying to achieve, `ViewModel` should handle the event and change states (or navigate to another screen) approprietly.

Composables should be reusable on different screens, and not dependent on any business logic. If you couple a small composable to a business logic, you won't be able to change the logic of this composable on other screens.

While this probably seems fine, imagine you want to use this same thumbnail composable on another screen, and when users clicks on it, you want to show some kind of an `AlertDialog`. Because you coupled the composable to a navigation event, you will either have to create a new composable of this thumbnail (for display of `AlertDialog`), or change the existing one to handle the event on higher-level composable, i.e. make composable not coupled to the business logic of navigating.

Comment: Actaully I the "business-logic-less" Composable could have been also used for creating "business-logic-full" composable connected to VM, therefore the UI could have still been reusable. But sure, the solution with ViewModel seems to be preffered one, thanks :)